# Understanding what is returned from a stream in Node

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm working on a project which uses streams. I'm actually streaming a Readable in ObjectMode to a transform stream which stringifies it and turns it into an object and then sends it along to my web framework's reply() method.

Everything works, but I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what is happening. Here is the working example:

```
var foo = new FooModel();
var stream = foo.all();

reply(stream.pipe(ObjectTransform));
```

Here, I'm making a call to a model which returns a stream readable in object mode. I then pipe that to an ObjectTransform class which is really just a transform stream that stringifies the objects that gets piped from stream.

But this is what I'm having trouble understanding:

```
reply(stream.pipe(ObjectTransform));
```

What does stream.pipe(ObjectTransform) return? I don't understand why I don't return the ObjectTransform stream since that is what is doing the stringification.

This would make more logical sense to me, but, obviously, it doesn't work that way:

```
var foo = new FooModel();
var stream = foo.all();
var stringified_stream = stream.pipe(ObjectTransform);

stringified_stream.pipe(reply);
```

Can someone break this down for me so I understand it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`src.pipe(dest)`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) returns the destination stream. This pattern allows for `pipe()` calls to be chained:

```
a.pipe(b).pipe(c).pipe(d)
// is equivalent to
a.pipe(b)
b.pipe(c)
c.pipe(d)
```

Your code then boils down to:

```
var foo = new FooModel();
var stream = foo.all();

// reply(stream.pipe(ObjectTransform));
stream.pipe(ObjectTransform);
reply(ObjectTransform);
```

As you write in your question, the "node way" to answer to a request would be to pipe a readable stream to a writable stream, such as `ObjectTransform.pipe(reply)`. In this way, you could one-line your code sample: `new FooModel().all().pipe(ObjectTransform).pipe(reply)`.

Obvioulsy this only works if `reply` is a writable stream: in your case it's a function which I guess internally pipes its argument to another stream so the previous paragraph doesn't apply there.

For more information about streams, you can read the [Stream Handbook](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook).